# How to persist PYTHONPATH setting of an Eclipse Pydev project?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I can setup a working PYTHONPATH using project properties, but it seems like after every reboot, I have to manually reset it. Is there a good way to persist the PYTHONPATH associated with a project?

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` set in project's properties is a **persistent** setting like all project's settings. You should change the question's title and describe what problem you exactly have with this setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set the PYTHONPATH for a project, pydev will create a .pydevproject file in the root of your project. Make sure that file is being properly written (it could be that your project is read-only or something like that which could prevent PyDev from writing that file where the settings are persisted).

If that's not your case, please take a look if there's something reported in your error log.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe instead of tweaking your project properties, you should try to change your pydev's settings.
I found [this tutorial](http://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/resources/Eclipse/eclipse-python-configuration.htm).Take a look at no 3 .

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Then you create new pydev project you can select option like "Add project to your python path". If you want you can customize python's intepreter and associated libs.