# Eclipse: "Python not configured"

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Here is a screenshot of whats happening:

[image: Python not configured]

Basically, I execute everything via command line but edit the source in eclipse.
This error prevents autocomplete which is annoying.

I have gone to `window>preferences>PyDev>Interpreter - Python` and set the correct values but they don't stay and even when I hit apply they don't seem to take for the current session.

Any idea on what could cause this error message?

Comment: Fixed this issue.  Dropbox messed up all my permissions and the .pydevproject file among other files were read only.  changed the permissions and everything is working now.

Answer (score 7):

What also works is RClick --> PyDev --> Remove PyDev Project Config.

[image: steps_screen_shoot]

Please note that the error marker may not be removed even after a clean/build, you may have te delete the marker manualy (just select it and delete) then clean, build and run

P.S.: I couldn't find the "project nature" option mentioned in the voted answer.

Comment: You can also just restart Eclipse if you're still seeing the error after clicking "Remove PyDev Project Config". That's what I did and it worked for me.

Comment: good choice if you want to remove the nature of the project. Then if will not be considered has a python project.

Answer (score 5):

Go to Window → Preferences. In the Preferences window, expand PyDev and select Interpreter-Python. Click "New..." and type Python32 for the Interpreter name. For the Interpreter executable, browse to your copy of Python (C:\Program Files\Python32\python.exe), and press Open.

Answer (score 3):

Project Properties > Project Natures and uncheck the python thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
       1. Select your project and right click and click on Properties
       2. Select PyDev-Interpreter/Grammer,click on "Click here to configure an    
          Interpreter not listed" Link.
```

Answer (score 1):

On Mac,

```
open eclipse application,   
click preferences    
click PyDev    
Click Interpreter  
Click Python Interpreter  (below Figure 1)
Click Choose from List button (below Figure 2)
Select what ever Python version you want to use  
Click Apply  
Click OK   
Exit Eclipse
ReOpen it and all fixed.
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The permssion issue (mentioned for `.pydevproject` in "[How to persist `PYTHONPATH` setting of an Eclipse Pydev project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249995/how-to-persist-pythonpath-setting-of-an-eclipse-pydev-project)") can easily happen in a DropBox settings when used by multiple users.

See for instance "[How to fix Drop Box permissions issues in 10.5](http://www.macworld.com/article/1136000/105dropbox.html)" (if you are on a Mac, but the general idea applies for other unix-like OS too)

> The permanent fix to this problem is to add the proper ACL to the Drop Box folder.
>   To do that, open Terminal, and enter this command—note that you can’t just copy and paste it as is, as you need to replace the two occurrences of short_username with your user’s actual short username.
>   For that reason, I suggest copying this into TextEdit, editing it as needed, and then pasting it into Terminal.

```
chmod +a "short_username allow list,add_file,search,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,writesecurity,chown,file_inherit,directory_inherit" /Users/short_username/Public/Drop\ Box
```

> After running this command, you should find that your Drop Box works as expected, and you have full rights to files that others leave for your use

Comment: I am having a similar issue and this solution didn't work for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Laura this issue seems related to permissions somehow, so beside double check those, I don't have other idea right now. Maybe check also if any other processes interfere with Eclipse or the python interpreter.