# Eclipse + Pydev wont keep interpreter setting within the same session.

Tags: python, eclipse, installation, pydev, interpreter

I'm attempting to get eclipse running as something more powerful than a colored text editor so that I can do some Maya scripting. There's literally nothing fancy about this setup, it just doesn't keep my interpreter once the prefs window is closed.

I can open and view .py docs fine, but pydev will not keep the interpreter I give it. As soon as I save the prefs with vanilla python.exe chosen as the interpreter, eclipse loses it. Opening the prefs again will show a blank interpreter page.

Auto config used to work before I started mucking with settings. I had the same disappearing problem even though Autoconfig could find everything.

c:\Python27 is set in my PYTHONPATH for user and system variables.

I've tried 32 and 64bit python (running win7 64). I was using Aptana with pydev and it seemed to not complain for a while, but then the interpreter went awol and I tried Eclipse to fix it. I can't start an actual project due to the missing interpreter, and the large "help" box that pops up when I'm typing is slowing me down considerably.

Eclipse 3.7.2
Python 2.7.2
Pydev 2.5

Thanks for your help, I'm pretty green at this.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://www.creativecrash.com/maya/tutorials/using-tools-scripts/c/using-eclipse-as-a-maya-ide)?

Answer (score 1):

I've been wresting with this problem all evening and just now solved it for me. My problem was with a workspace saved in Google Drive, but where Drive had created a lot of files with a (1) before the first period in the .metadata folder, presumably as a conflict resolution thing.

Using File Commander (the search in Windows 7 ignored the parenthesis ?!) I searched for all the files containing (1) and delted them. (It should be said I made a copy of the folder first and opened it as a workspace to experiment on, as I've never figured out how to import a project once the workspace is lost.)

In my case, it worked like a charm. Now I'm going to be very nervous about having Eclipse open on both coding machines at once. We'll see how it goes from here.

Comment: Same thing here with Dropbox. The conflicted files somehow interefered.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. This is how I solved it:

1. Go to your workspace folder.
2. Edit the file ".pydevproject".
3. Change the path located after "PYTHON_PROJECT_INTERPRETER" pydev property.
4. Save and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem, and the issue was that **.project** and **.pydevproject** were ***read only*** and Eclipse couldn't save the configurations.

Solution: make **.project** and **.pydevproject** writable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have something in your error log?
2. Have you tried pressing 'apply' after you configure the interpreter?
3. The interpreter configuration should be stored in your workspace .metadata, can you check if that folder is writable for you? (you can check the workspace used in window > preferences > general > startup and shutdown > workspaces).
4. It seems the question: [Eclipse: "Python not configured"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669846/why-eclipse-is-saying-that-python-not-configured) may also be related...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in fedora, disappearing interpreter settings. The issue was Eclipse couldn't write to the folder even after granting read+write access.

Solution: Go to terminal and type: sudo eclipse
enter admin password to run as admin. Solved