# Eclipse cannot save python2.7 interpretor

Tags: eclipse, save, settings, pydev, interpreter

Though this is strange but happening with me. I add python3.2 in in the Pydev> interpreter-python it is saved for always. I can run my scripts pretty well. But when I add a 'python2.7' in the Pydev> interpreter-python it shows there till preferences window is open and once I close the preferences window it disappears and takes other interpreters with it. I mean an empty 'interpreter-python' setting.

I save my workspace in dropbox so that I can use share my settings on different systems both using Ubuntu 12.04 X64. I am sure it is not a Dropbox ACL setting issue as 'Python3.2' settings save and work pretty well until I add 'python2.7' which removes all the interpreters including itself.

Please Help. Unable to code.

AK

Comment: Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10673856/110451 (seems to be the same issue with different symptoms)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem and Fabio's proposition didn't help. From my understanding, the general interpreter settings shouldn't even be saved in the dropbox project folder, but in the aptana folder. Any ideas?